# Get Ibeacon name

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have multiple beacons with the same UUID ı use CoreLocation to scan this beacons;

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
           // extendBackgroundRunningTime()
            if beacons.count > 0 {
                for beacon in beacons {
                    print(region.identifier)
                    print(beacons[0].proximityUUID)            
                }
                    
                
            } else {
 }
```

I want to get ibeacon specific name. İs it possible or not? Also is there any way to distinguish each beacons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only distinguish beacons via their `proximityUUID`, `major` and `minor`.

iBeacons do not have a name.

Some vendors may allow you to name a beacon in their setup app, but this name is not part of the iBeacon standard and is not visible via Core Location.

Normally all of your beacons would have the same `proximityUUID` so that you can discover them with a single beacon region.  You then use specific `major` and `minor` values to determine the beacon that you have discovered.

You can read about the format of an iBeacon advertisement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon?wprov=sfti1)

Comment: thanks. But we use the same minor and major and uuıd to scan let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 0, minor: 0, identifier: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx").  I can not understand why we dont access beacon name using CoreLocation. This brings extra work for us:(

Comment: As I said, the iBeacon specification doesn't include a name. There is limited space in a Bluetooth advertising packet. To make efficient use of that space an iBeacon advertises the uuid and two 16 bit numbers; major and minor. This allows for 4,294,967,296 unique IBeacons per uuid. More than enough. I am sorry that you didn't understand how IBeacons work when you set them up, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: When you specify your beacon region you typically specify only the uuid, leaving the major and minor undefined. Then, once you enter a region you begin ranging and identify the specific beacon based on its major and minor.

Comment: thanks for useful commend. I will take this information and make the necessary updates.